# xamarin formsでMainActivity.cs から MainPage.xaml.cs のメソッドを呼ぶ方法

Tags: xamarin

タイトル通りですが、xamarin formsでAndroidのMainActivity.cs から MainPage.xaml.cs のメソッドを呼ぶ方法がわかれば教えてください。
やりたいことはAndroidで時間のかかる処理等で、CallBackがあった場合にそれをMainPage.xaml.cs側に伝えたいと思っています。
MainPage.xaml.csからAndroidのMainActivity.cs側はDependencyServiceで呼び出しができると思いますが、その逆方向になります。
デリゲート等を登録して、それを呼ぶ方法で可能なのでしょうか？
それとも何らかのインターフェースが用意されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

デリゲート登録でうまくいきました。
解決とさせていただきます。